# General SVN directory

Tags: svn

I have SVN addres `http://somesvn.intra/svn/somepro/` that contains project I need to work on. When I do checkot I got souch directory structure:

```
linux
--source
----branch
----tag
----trunk
win
--source
----branch
----tag
----trunk
```

This looks strange for me since I was expecting to get directly to source location. Is it ok to go directly to `http://somesvn.intra/svn/somepro/win/source/trunk/`
do checkout, edit and commit without affecting for example Linux project's trunk commit? I'm afraid I will see `win/trunk` project changes in `linux/trunk` project svn log.

Comment: You can checkout a working copy anchored at any directory within the repository and it is quite normal to use a project's trunk or a specific branch as a working copy.

Comment: Not sure why they have a 'source' directory under each one, but the rest looks legit. 'linux' and 'win' would be considered as separate projects.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, typically the trunk is the "master" copy, so to speak. You typically wouldn't checkout the `BASE URL`, you would usually either check out the trunk, or one of the directories underneath branches. It's perfectly acceptable to use the trunk as the working copy if that's your development team's paradigm.

---

More in-depth: Yes, the paradigm for svn development is that usually the `trunk` is the working development directory that teams will base their work off of. Usually developers on a team will work on separate features/bugs, but instead of everyone working on the `trunk` and possibly causing conflicts with each other. Typically devs will make branches and once their changes are complete, they will merge their changes back into the trunk. Using your example, you would see something like:

```
linux
--source
----branch
------vico-branch (contains source)
----tag
----trunk (contains source)
win
--source
----branch
----tag
----trunk
```